# Databricks cluster failing to start

Tags: databricks, gcp-databricks

Cluster terminated.Reason:Cloud provider launch failure

A cloud provider error was encountered while launching worker nodes. See the Databricks guide for more information.

GCP error message: Compute Quota Exceeded for databricksharish2022 in region asia-southeast1: Quota: SSD_TOTAL_GB, used 0.0 and requested 1000.0 out of 500.0